# Drop down list that displays name in list but automatically turns into a coded variable. Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel 2016, I am using [data validation > apply lists] to make a drop down list of values that can be chosen for a cell of a given column. For example, for the variable sex, the drop down list provides "Male" or "Female."[Drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLm0Z.png).

I would like to code this variable without losing the drop down list. E.g. "Male" and "Female" display on the drop down, but automatically change to their coded version "0" and "1" after they are clicked.

I have tried a few Macros that have not worked for me. I don't want to use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH because I cannot have a separate column with the coded variables (only one column for "Sex" variable).

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet.Change` event to overwrite the value with its corresponding coded version.